# Timthumb not working with WordPress 4.0

Tags: thumbnails, timthumb

I just updated WordPress to the latest version, 4.0, and I had a bad surprise - timthumb stopped working. the thumbnails are not generated. I cleared theme's cache folder, and checked to see if chmod is 755 - it is. timthumb is also updated to the latest version.
 this is how I call the thumbnail

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php get_image_url(); ?>&amp;h=170&amp;w=170&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
```

What else can I do?

thank you

Comment: Is it for featured thumb image for post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. seems that the problem was with a file added in wp-content - for security reasons, I added a .htaccess file to wp-content folder, and that was blocking timthumb. In case others have problems, remember not to limit access to wp-content.

Answer (score 1):

If folder permission are correct then it should work.
Anyway try this one. And let me know how it goes.

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php $featured_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); echo $featured_image_url[0]; ?>&amp;h=170&amp;w=170&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" />
```

Comment: that is still not working